# Solve the equation $\Delta u=0$ in the domain $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \gt a^2 \}$ with the boundary condition $u=1+3\sin \theta$ on the circle $r=a$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the equation $\Delta u=0$ in the domain $D=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \gt a^2 \}$ with the boundary condition $u=1+3\sin \theta$ on the circle $r=a$ and with the condition is bounded for $r \to \infty$.

My try:

Since this is an unbounded domain, I try substituting $s=\frac{1}{r}$.The laplacian in $r$ and $\theta$ is given by $$u_{rr}+\frac{u_r}{r}+\frac{u_{\theta \theta}}{r^2}=0$$.

Then  the region comes out to be the inside of a disc which can be easily solved.

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in polar coordinates :
$$u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta}=0$$
Search of particular solutions thanks to separation of variables method leads to :
$$u(r,\theta)=\left(c_1\sin(\theta)+C_1\cos(\theta)\right)\left(c_2\frac{1}{r}+C_2r\right)+constant$$
The bounded condition at $r=\infty$ implies $C_2=0$

The condition $u(a,\theta)=1+3\sin(\theta)$ implies $C_1=0$ and $constant=1$ and $c_1\left(c_2\frac{1}{a}\right)=3$. Hense $c_1c_2=3a$. The result is :
$$u(r,\theta)=\frac{3a}{r}\sin(\theta)+1$$

Comment: Can we use separation of variables in unbounded domains??

Comment: Why not, if the result satisfies the PDE ?